# spring boot with jasypt jvm argument alternative

Tags: spring-boot, jasypt

I know that spring boot works with jasypt, by supplying jvm argument -Djasypt.encryptor.password=password , the framework will use it to decrypt. However, in my use case, we cannot supply jvm argument, how do i do this programtically in code instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the argument manullay in your code.

```
System.setProperty("jasypt.encryptor.password", "password");
```

You see more details [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-jasypt)